# c program to calculate the amount of memory usage by the system?

Tags: c, linux, memory

How do i know the amount of memory used . i.e RAM usage ?

```
int main()
{
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
     {
        printf("%d\n",i);
     }
return 0;
}
```

I want to write a code which calculate the amount of memory used by this program . May be like-

```
int main()
{
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
     {
        printf("%d\n",i);
     }
  printf("Amount of memory consumed=%f",SOME_FUNCTION());
return 0;
}
```

Comment: may be just keep counting the amount of space used by counting from the  variable declaration statements Like for int i=0; ---> add 4 bytes and for char b; add 1byte  and so on

Answer (score 2):

The `getrusage` system call will return a handful of information for the current process, among which is the "resident set size":

```
struct rusage usage;

if (!getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage)) {
    printf("Maximum resident set size (KB): %ld\n", usage.ru_maxrss);
} else {
    perror("getrusage");
}
```

This size equates to the amount of memory that is physically wired to the process and not the entire size of the virtual address space, parts of which might be paged-out or never loaded.

Comment: Works fine. Needs `#include <sys/resource.h>`

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach will to create a wrapper function for memory allocation and freeing and call the wrapper and put memory usage information in that. This can only be used in case of dynamic memory allocaion. e.g

```
#define ALLOC 1
#define FREE 2
mem_op(void * pointer,int size,int operation)
{
    switch(operation)
    {
        static int mem_used;
        case ALLOC:
            // call malloc or alloc
            mem_used = mem_used+size;
            break;

        case FREE:
            // call free
            mem_used = mem_used-size;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: The code snipped would be clearer if it were a little more complete. Explanations should not be indented and separated from the code by a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to check how much memory your program uses on Linux system. but most likely what you want to check is the value of VmRSS in `/proc/[pid]/status` (or second column of `/proc/[pid]/statm`). VmRSS ("resident set size") is the amount of memory your process currently uses.

Other than that you may be interested in VmSize from `/proc/[pid]/status` (or first column of `/proc/[pid]/statm`). This is total memory your process uses, including memory swapped out, memory used by shared libraries, memory-mapped resources (which, in general, don't consume real RAM).

To get PID of your process, use `getpid()`. From within your process you could also check `/proc/self/status`.